# Reloading View does not update all of the controls on the form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a view the contains an @Html.DropDownListFor. When the form/view loads, if one of the model properties has values (IEnumerable), then it will create a bunch of divs with the corresponding data. If that property does not have any values (aka Count() == 0), then it is supposed to show a single button on the form (which will create the data for that property).

So, when the user selects one of the options from the Dropdown, I fire an ajax call to the exact same action method that populated the current form/view, but this time, it sends a value in the id field.

I have a breakpoint in my action method and I verified that it is getting hit, and it has the correct parameter value and creates the correct data for the model that gets passed to the view, BUT...when the model is sent to the view to re-populate, NONE of the items/controls on the form change. I even put breakpoints in the cshtml file and it's going through there with the correct data also.

So, here's my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
        {
            var seasonId = id;

            if (seasonId == null)
            {
                var player = _playerRepository.Query().FirstOrDefault(p => p.PlayerId == _userIdentity.PlayerId);

                if (player.DefaultSeasonId != null)
                    seasonId = (int)player.DefaultSeasonId;
                else
                {
                    return View(new ScheduleModel
                    {
                        Player = player,
                        AvailableSeasons = _seasonRepository.Query().Select(s => s)
                    });
                }
            }

            return View(CreateScheduleModelForSeason((int)seasonId));
        }
```

Here's the beginning of my view:

```
@model LeagueManager.Models.ScheduleModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Schedule(s)";
}

<div class="row">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AvailableSeasons)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedSeasonId, new SelectList(Model.AvailableSeasons, "SeasonId", "SeasonName"), new { id = "seasonSelect" })
</div>

<form method="post" action="Schedule/GenerateSchedule">
    <h2>The Season's Schedules/Weeks and Matchups</h2>

    <div>
        <div>
            @if (Model.SchedulesAndMatches == null || (Model.SchedulesAndMatches != null && !Model.SchedulesAndMatches.Any()))
            {
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Generate Schedule" />
            }
        </div>
```

And here's the ajax call:

```
@* Season Selector *@
$('select#seasonSelect').change(function () {
    var selectedSeasonId = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Schedule/Index',
        data: { id: selectedSeasonId }
    });
});
```

Again, all of the actual code is working, it's just not re-rendering the view...

Example: when calling the ActionResult method with an id = 1, it loads the entire schedule. When switching to id = 2 via the dropdown (then getting called again via the ajax), it stays with the same schedule.

On the flip side: when calling the ActionResult method with an id = 2, it loads the single button. When switching to id = 1 via the dropdown, it re-populates the correct data in the model, but the view/form does not reflect the new information.

Please help!

Comment: Can you please explain further what you need exactly? do you want to update the drop down list when you select an option from the drop down list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call action using ajax you can’t return view, you have to return json data.
So your solution is remove ajax call and set window.location with your post url..

```
@* Season Selector *@
$('select#seasonSelect').change(function () {
    var selectedSeasonId = $(this).val();

    window.location = '/Schedule/Index/' + selectedSeasonId;        

});
```

Comment: Awesome! I'd like to say I forgot about that, but this is only my 3rd ajax call I've written. Works perfect now, thank you!